# There has been an error processing your request magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9, reports, log

It seems that my website is not working and it showing errors.

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: `272747104501`

Please help me to find the solution

> a:5:{i:0;s:48:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory";i:1;s:1654:"#0 /home/lalcointeriors/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(109): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
>       #1 /home/lalcointeriors/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(320): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
>       #2 /home/lalcointeriors/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
>       #3 /home/lalcointeriors/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
>       #4 /home/lalcointeriors/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
>       #5 /home/lalcointeriors/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(169): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
>       #6 /home/lalcointeriors/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
>       #7 /home/lalcointeriors/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(141): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_setup')
>       #8 /home/lalcointeriors/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(234): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->__construct('core_setup')
>       #9 /home/lalcointeriors/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
>       #10 /home/lalcointeriors/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
>       #11 /home/lalcointeriors/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>       #12 /home/lalcointeriors/public_html/index.php(92): Mage::run('', 'store')
>       #13 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}

Comment: check the error log file with given number in `var/report` folder

Answer (score 1):

You have to go to the folder at the root of your Magento `var/report`.
Here you can find a file named `272747104501` in it you will find the detail of your error and the PHP stack leading to this error.

If you want to disable this feature and display the error directly in your browser **warning not do this in production mode** :
You can go in the `errors/` directory at the root of your Magento and rename / copy the file `local.xml.sample` to `local.xml`. In it you can find the node `config/report/action` that means the error will be printed in your frontend instead of sending you an email and displaying the report number.
You can also replace `print` by `email` and set your email into `email_address` node that will send you the error details by email.

---

**EDIT**
A report file look like this

```
a:5:{i:0;s:53:"ERROR DESCRIPTION"   
#0 .... => here the file and line generating your error    
#1 ....   
#2 ....   
#3 ....
```

---

**EDIT**
That means your MySQL server is down or with a bad configuration.
Without showing us, check in `app/etc/local.xml` file if the informations are correct.
 - If there are not, fill them
 - If they are, contact your hosting company to start or check MySQL status

Comment: There is lots of file created in var/report nad no .maintenance.flag is there

Comment: I did not tell you about the maintenance.flag file, it is not the problem here. If there is a lot of file it juste that your website is generating a lot fo error. You have to inspect that error following my answer way.

Comment: Please see my updated answer, I explain to you how to find your error using the report file

Comment: Why number changes when i refresh page

Comment: Magento is generating a new report even if the error is the same, that is normal. You have to take a look at the file content.

Comment: Please see updated question

Comment: See my update, you have a MySQL issue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in your root folder one **hidden** file is generated `.maintenance.flag` remove that.

and check your `var/report/272747104501` file.

**EDIT**

It seems you try to connect to mysql via a socket and that fails. Is Mysql running right and is your configuration right.

The error is coming from the file you did mention, so that isn't the problem, Magento does see that file.

**Solution**

Try using an IP to connect to Mysql. Or check if your mysql-socket is right.

Comment: There is lots of file created in var/report nad no .maintenance.flag is there

Comment: it will generate when you refresh your page from browser so, the just concern with last generated number file `272747104501` paste in your question.

Comment: Why number changes when i refresh page

Comment: its generating files when you refresh page, open that file and paste that content in your question

Comment: Please see updated question

Comment: check my updated answer and check your `app/etc/local.xml` file database connection